# In C++, how to setup a char grid2d[x][y] with variables

Tags: c++, arrays

```
char grid2d[x][y];
```

Does not work because it is expecting constants (or defines) for each index. My problem is that these values are not known until runtime, yet I need to use this signature since I'm calling a function that expects that exact format (and I cannot change that interface).

Any ideas on how to get this to work? I can't use define's for the same reason (values not known until runtime).

Comment: Generally, you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of dynamic arrays.

Comment: btw you shouldnt use `#define` to define constants anyhow, thats a source of super confusing errors

Comment: VLAs (Variable Length Arrays) are not even a standard C++ feature...

Comment: How does the function argument look like exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `std::vector` to get a container that allows dynamic sizing at runtime.

For example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid2d;
```

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment

Answer (score 1):

You could use pointer to pointer to char as signature.

```
 void func(char **grid2d)
 {
      //use grid2d[1][2]
 }
 int main()
 {
     //input x and y
     char **grid2d;
     grid2d=new char*[x];
     for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
        grid2d[i]=new char[y];
     func(grid2d);
 }
```

Or you could simply use `std::vector`

```
void func(vector<vector<char> > grid2d)
{
     //use grid2d[1][2]
}
int main()
{
     //input x and y
     vector<vector<char> > grid2d(x,vector<char>(y));
     func(grid2d);
}
```